# Creating Weekly Reports

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, reports, designer

I want to create a weekly report that looks at the frequency of the distinct items in the "Created By" column on an incoming email library. Is there a way I could automate this, such as a workflow?

So far I have tried creating a view that shows me only the current weeks items and put a sorted by "Created by" and count on "created by". The problem is I have to export this view to excel every week and at the same time every week or the data could be off.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerShell cmdlets to filter and export the items into Excel. Then create a Scheduled windows task to run the cmdlets weekly.
[Export SharePoint List Items to CSV using PowerShell](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/04/export-sharepoint-list-items-to-csv-using-powershell.html)

[Creating a Scheduled Task in Windows 10](https://www.technipages.com/scheduled-task-windows)